# Is RotatingFileHandler thread-safe in Python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

In a project I am using rotatingfilehandler for logs. It is configured to have size of 5M and backup count of 2. Log handler is used by different threads. The program crashes after a while with the following error:

> "File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\logging\handlers.py",
>   line 70, in emit
>       self.doRollover()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 70, in emit
>       self.doRollover()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 171, in doRollover
>       self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 171, in doRollover
>       self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 111, in rotate
>       os.rename(source, dest)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 111, in rotate
>       os.rename(source, dest) PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

I think it happens because logger try to rename the file while it is already open in another thread. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are they actually operating in different threads? Or are they different *processes*?

As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) explain

> logging to a single file from multiple processes is not supported, because there is no standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple processes in Python

Those same docs also outline some possible solutions to this problem, such as using a multiprocessing `Lock`, which I won't replicate here.